# Html5 download attribute works

Tags: html, attributes

```
<a href="Untitled.jpg" download> download image </a>
```

This code is used to download a image. When i load the page `Untitled.jpg` not come to the browser but there is no request for the image after i click on the link but the download is works fine ( I detect this behavior by inspecting network tab in chrome). what is going in here ?

Answer (score 0):

This attribute is not supported yet on `IE` and `Safari`. And you need to supply a file for download:

```
<a href="Untitled.jpg" download="/images/some.jpg"> download image </a>
```